# html or javascript code to keep refreshing even after the website goes down

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I have a issue where we want a webpage to keep reloading at an interval even if the server hosting the code goes down.  This is so that if the server goes down, it will keep trying to refresh the page so that when the server does come back up, it will recover.  There seems to be a ton of ways to refresh/reload a page based on interval or demand, but I can't find a way to have the page recover automatically after the server eventually comes back online.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks,

Comment: If the server hosting the page goes down, your page is down, unless you have a redundant or backup server to take its place

Comment: then you keep retrying until the server comes back. the server is not going to be able to reach out to TELL you it's back. you can only keep trying/failing until you DO get a response

Comment: Don't reload the entire page. Use an ajax call in the interval and update only the relevant part of the page.

Comment: Why would the server go down? If it's down there's no way to get the initial page or the js associated with it. this is certainly not a scenario that should be happening? Maybe you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: We recently had an issue where the hosting server went down and the page that was set to refresh every 60 seconds,  just so happened to coincide with the brief outage leaving the display with a server not answering  message.  I was hoping for a simpler answer, but I think Thomas's suggestion of ajax might be the way to go.  @ThomasGhesquiere can the ajax code continue to run if the server providing the data goes down?  Can anyone suggest a site of an example of that type of code?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using iframe to contain the entire website. the host site should not reload